How do I go about "searching your distribution's package database for the missing files" to get the GUI working for Ubuntu Linux?
In the Bitcoin Core instructions, it says that to use the GUI, you have to execute bitcoin-qt. It gives this explanation for a potential obstacle:

If all the required libraries are installed, Bitcoin Core will start. If a required library is missing, an error message similar to the following message will be displayed:
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Search your distribution’s package database for the missing file missing and install package containing that file. Then re-run /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt to see if it’s missing another file. Repeat until Bitcoin Core GUI starts.

I got the same error described, just, with a different result:
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-xinerama.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried:
sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama.so.0

and got:
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
E:Unable to locate package libxcb-xinerama.so.0 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libxcb-xinerama.so.0'

Tried:
apt search libxcb-xinerama.so.0

and got:
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

So, basically I've got no clue what to do.

Can you try sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0?

@VojtěchStrnad Thanks! this worked, not sure why, but it worked

The file libscb-xinerama.so.0 is provided by the libxcb-xinerama0 package. Installing that package (sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0) will make that file available.
If you go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/, you can search packages by their contents.

Or, instead of searching for a lacking file with the browser, use apt-file as described here.
